# ggplot line with multiple colors by a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following codes plot the first graph. but I want to color the lines by the variable `factor1`.
Is there a simple way?

```
data <- data.frame(factor1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                   factor2 = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
                         x = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
                         y = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15,16)
                   )

p <- ggplot2::ggplot(data, aes(x, y, colour = factor(factor2))) +
  ggplot2::geom_line( )

print(p)
```

The current output:
[image]

My desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your colour option is providing a hint to the grouping. Try the following instead:

```
p <- ggplot2::ggplot(data)
p +
  aes(x, y, group = factor(factor2), colour = factor(factor1)) + 
  geom_line()
```

This should result in the following graph:

[image: plot with factored grouping & color]

If you want to show the legend for each of the series in the group, you can add another geometry like point shapes:

```
p +
  aes(x, y) +
  aes(
    group = factor(factor2),
    shape= factor(factor2),
    color = factor(factor1)
  ) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(shape="factor1", colour="factor2")
```

Which will result in the following:

[image]

If you'd like to have more control over graph, you might consider reshaping the data.

See the following for additional information about formatting legends with multiple groups:

[R Graph Gallery (custom layout legend)](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/239-custom-layout-legend-ggplot2.html)

[R Cookbook (legends)](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2))

Answer (score 0):

To color by `factor1`, while drawing lines for groups given by `factor2`, map `factor1` on `color` aesthetic and `factor2` on `group` aesthetic (Note: To make clear why there are two lines with same colors I would suggest to map factor2 on shape, linewidth ...).

```r
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(factor1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                   factor2 = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
                   x = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
                   y = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15,16)
)

# Plot with lines colored by factor1.
# Map factor1 on color and factor2 on group
p <- ggplot2::ggplot(data, 
                     aes(x, y, 
                         colour = factor(factor1), 
                         group = factor(factor2))) +
  ggplot2::geom_line() 
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>